# Can you define an operator (***) in F#?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, operators, arrows

I'm working on Arrows in F# and I wanted to create a `***` operator.  I note, however, that `(***)`, the necessary way to express an operator in a function definition, overlaps with the F# block comment syntax.  So how could you actually express this?

I thought of maybe `.***.` but I think that will actually treat the dots as part of the operator, which I'd rather avoid.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, but you need to add spaces between the parentheses and the asterisks:

```
let ( *** ) x y = x * y

let z = 4 *** 5
```